# haproxy hide backend url

Tags: reverse-proxy, tomcat, haproxy

Is it possible to hide the backend server's URL path, using haproxy?
The backend server's URL path is `https://backend:8443/backend_url(/.*)`
I would like to keep the URL path in the browser as always as `https://haproxy/haproxy_url(/.*)`

The backend application runs in tomcat and has some j_spring_security_check that breaks normal rewriting and proxying, which is why I am trying to use haproxy to reverse proxy it.
I also need to reuse port 443 on haproxy for multiple applications, and haproxy hosts the organizational wildcard cert for all incoming SSL traffic.

With my current configuration, the haproxy URL changes from `https://haproxy/haproxy_url(.)` to  `https://haproxy/backend_url(/.*)`.

How do I keep it always `https://haproxy/haproxy_url(/.*)`?

My current configuration is:

```
frontend https-in
    bind *:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/ssl/domain.pem
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 443
    # set HTTP Strict Transport Security (HTST) header
    rspadd  Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=15768000
    # some ACLs and URL rewrites...
    default_backend https-in-backends

backend https-in-backends
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(Host)]
    http-request del-header X-Forwarded-Port
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    stick                   on src
    stick-table             type ip size 10240k expire 60m
    acl                     no_redir url_beg   /haproxy_url
    reqirep                 ^([^\ :]*)\ /haproxy_url(.*)       \1\ /backend_url\2
    rspirep                 ^([^\ :]*)\ (.*)/haproxy_url(.*)    \1\ \2/backend_url/\3
    server backend_srv backend1:8443/backend_url ssl verify none
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by modifying the response back to the browser, in the backend configuration. Don't know if this is the accepted way of doing this, but it worked for me.

`rspirep ^(Location:)\ https://([^/]*)/backend_url(.*)$ \1\ https://\2/haproxy_url\3`

Unfortunately j_spring_security_check is still borking everything. :-(